# How to read data in small parts from a file while using XMLStreamReader?

Tags: java, xml, io, xmlstreamreader

So currently I am using `XMLStreamReader` to read through a file I have. In the file there are the tags `<Data> ... </Data>` . Within these tags is a huge amount of Base64 encoded data. The data can be as big as 20MB.  I use `XMLStreamReader` to reach this  `<Data>` tag and then I want to read the data in parts and write it to another file. I am basically transferring `<Data> ... </Data>`  content to another file. How can I get the data in small parts from `XMLStreamReader` and write it to another file? Is it possible to couple `XMLStreamReader` with some form of `InputStream` and use `byte[]` of comfortable size? Below is my current code

```
Public void readXML(File file){
XMLInputFactory inpFac = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(tmpFile)
XMLStreamReader reader = inpFac.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
While(reader.hasNext())
{
If(reader.isStartElement() && reader.getName().getLocalPart().equals("Data")){
File imgFile=new File("img.txt");
try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(imgFile);){
fw.write(reader.getElementText());//need to avoid this , can't get all data at once
writer.flush();
}
}
```

Basically instead of doing `reader.getElementText()` I want to get the data in small portions (maybe by using Byte[]?). Is it possible to convert the XMLStreamReader to a BufferedReader and read line by line ? Is it possible to wrap BufferedReader around XMLStreamReader ? Please let me know how I can make the question better as I am new to SO

Comment: I think you can work on text chunks with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#getTextCharacters-int-char:A-int-int-

Comment: Hii. Thank you so much it worked out perfectly!